# Set TeXstudio for Unicode .Rnw files (Sweave)

Tags: xetex, unicode, r, sweave

I tried to run Sweave on a `.Rnw` file from TeXstudio, but the unicode characters don't show up in the `.tex` file when I typeset with `xelatex`.

My user command is `/usr/local/bin/Rscript -e "Sweave('%.Rnw', encoding = 'utf8')"`.

The MWE document is the following.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<>>=
1 + 2
@

ɑʃɱɪ àüõ

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeXstudio seems not to call the `locale` as expected, so it is necessary to set the `locale` within the user command in TeXstudio:

```
/usr/local/bin/Rscript -e "Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL', 'en_US.UTF-8'); Sweave('%.Rnw', encoding = 'utf8')"
```

The `Rscript` path should be changed according to your OS.